# rails - outputting user input with Paragraph Returns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a textarea input that allows users to input in more than on paragraph, meaning the user can output a new line.

Problem is when I output that from the database it's all shrunk into one line?

How do I make that new line into an HTML friendly new line so it looks the way the user inputted the text?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) helper. It's replace all \n by `<br />` or `<p>`

Examples from API :

```
 my_text = "Here is some basic text...\n...with a line break."

  simple_format(my_text)
  # => "<p>Here is some basic text...\n<br />...with a line break.</p>"

  more_text = "We want to put a paragraph...\n\n...right there."

  simple_format(more_text)
  # => "<p>We want to put a paragraph...</p>\n\n<p>...right there.</p>"

  simple_format("Look ma! A class!", :class => 'description')
  # => "<p class='description'>Look ma! A class!</p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

This css rule should do the trick:
`white-space: pre-line;`

Answer (score -2):

This also works.
Put this in your imput show (**change** to your **class** and **attribute**, *tex: @post.content or @post.body*).

```
<%= @class.attribute.html_safe.gsub(/\r\n?/,"<br/>").html_safe %>
```